# Working on a local reference variable

Tags: c++

I was expecting the following code to result in undefined behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void incrementElements(vector<T> &v)
{
    for(typename vector<T>::size_type index = 0; index < v.size(); ++index)
    {
        T& local = v[index];
        ++local;
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        cout << v[v.size() - 1] << endl;
    }
    incrementElements(v);
    for(vector<int>::size_type index = 0; index < v.size(); ++index)
    {
        cout << v[index] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I give a reference to my vector element to a local variable then increment it.
I expected that when the local variable's lifetime ends the vector's memory would get cleaned as well resulting in empty references.
Except it did give a correct output.
Is this the compiler being smart enough and fixing this behavior or is this an acceptable way to code this?

I compiled using g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

**EDIT**
To specify my main confusion, I wrongly was under the assumption that a reference created  some sort of hard link that was equivalent to how the original variable was declared.
in my current understanding, is the following using a pointer equal:

```
    for(typename vector<T>::size_type index = 0; index < v.size(); ++index)
    {
        T* local = &v[index];
        ++(*local);
    }
```

Comment: The reference disappears, not the element inside `v`. Also doing exactly what you want is a possible outcome from undefined behavior so this is not a good way to check for it.

Comment: References can never shorten the lifetime of anything. Your loop body is equivalent to `++v[index];`. (Side note: the word "reference" in C++ does not mean the same thing as the word "reference" in Java and similar languages.)

Comment: The lifetime of the vector ends when `main` exits. You can add and remove names for the vector during that lifetime; but the lifetime remains as it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

- When you have UB the program can behave in any way, including the possibility of it working "correctly" (i.e. giving expected results)
- There is no such thing as "empty reference"

Your code itself is fine, it's ok to have a reference to an object go out of scope. It is not ok to have the object that is being referenced to to go out of scope before the reference does (but note that there are cases when a const reference prolongs the lifetime of the object) and then to try use it via the reference.

Comment: When you have UB the program can behave in any way, including remove all data from your HDD ;-)

Comment: So does the reference in this case behave equivalent as if I had taken a pointer to the element?

Comment: @turoni, well that would be a little innacurate. Think of it as of an alias. When the block starts you say "From now on I'm going to call this particular vector element a 'local'". When the block ends and the reference goes out of scope you simply stop calling this particular vector element a 'local', which of course doesn't affect the referenced element itself.

Comment: `It is not ok to have the object that is being referenced to to go out of scope before the reference does` Note that this by itself doesn't cause UB. It's "OK" to have dangling references, just not OK to use them. Also, when a reference extends the lifetime, then the object didn't "go out of scope", so it isn't technically an exception to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

```
for(typename vector<T>::size_type index = 0; index < v.size(); ++index)
{
    T& local = v[index];
    ++local;
}
```

is analogous to

```
int i = 0;
{
   int& ref = i;
   ++ref;  // Changes the value of i
}
```

At the end of that, you would expect to see the value of `i` to be 1.

1. `ref` lives only in the nested scope. It can't be used outside the nested scope. It does not change the life of `i`.
2. Value of `i` is changed inside the nested scope through `ref`. `i` continues to be alive after the nested scope ends.